# Is it correct to call await() twice when deleting data from Firebase using Kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, kotlin-coroutines

I have implemented Firebase Authentication in my project. My requirements are, when I sign-out the user to:

1. Delete Firebase Authentication account.
2. Delete user account from Firestore.

In my repository class, I have this function:

```
suspend fun signOut() {
    try {
        auth.currentUser?.apply {
            delete().await() //Delete Firebase Authentication account
            usersRef.document(uid).delete().await() //Delete Firestore data
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

This code works fine, but is it ok to call two await() functions, one after another? Is there a better/safer approach?

This is how I call signOut() from the ViewModel  class:

```
fun signOut() = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
    emit(repository.signOut())
}
```

Comment: If `delete()` was implemented as a normal `suspend fun` call instead of returning a `Task`, it would behave exactly as you wrote it -- awaiting on the completion immediately after submitting it. Since calling two suspendable functions is a perfectly legitimate practice, so is this.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Thank you so much for taking the time to comment to my question. So you say that it doesn't matter if I use two different suspend functions or a single one with two await() calls one after another (as in my code), it's perfectly fine, right?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik If that's the case, I think you should write an answer, because you answered my question and cleared my doubts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call any number of suspendable functions in a single function's body, they are no different from plain functions in this respect.

The reason you make those `await()` calls is just a consequence of using an API based on `Task`, `Deferred`, `Future`, etc., which essentially creates concurrency every time you call such a function.

In Kotlin, such an API would be considered legacy and the best-practice API would have suspendable functions that do the work of `await()` internally. In that case, calling such a function looks and behaves exactly the same as if it wasn't suspendable.